# how to set a condition that when the starting time is greater than the input time the code should exceute

Tags: python, datetime, time

I want to compare the current time with the same time added 4 hours later. I want to know how to initiate and keep the 4 hours later time intact even if the code is stopped running. And in any point of time if I run the code it should validate the later time with now time and if the now time is greater than later time it should change the later time.

I tried using datetime function in python. But the later time always resets and as a issue the `if` condition never executes.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
now=datetime.today().hour
later = datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=20)
print(later)
if now < later:
    later = datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=20)
    print("Yes")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to write a later time to a .txt file, followed by reading when you run the script?:

```
with open("latertime.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    file.write(later)
```

And by analogy at the beginning of the script:

```
with open("latertime.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    later = file.read()
```

If necessary, you can make the .txt file invisible using subprocess module:

```
subprocess.call(["attrib", "+h", "latertime.txt"])
```